# Using the object id in django forms

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

Why can't I access the object id in the `def clean(self)`?
I get the error:

> **'CheckInForm' object has no attribute 'id'**.

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Student
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError


class CheckInForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ['room', 'name']
        widgets = {'room': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
                   'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
                   }

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(CheckInForm, self).clean()
        new_room = cleaned_data.get('room')

        if Student.objects.filter(room=new_room).count() > 3:
            print(Student.objects.filter(room=new_room).count())
            if not Student.objects.filter(room=new_room, id=self.id):
                raise ValidationError('The room is full')
```

**models.py**

```
class Student(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_index=True)
    room = models.CharField(max_length=8, db_index=True, blank=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `self.instance.pk`

I guess you need to add check if it is create or update before filtering `Student` with `id` in your `clean()` method

```
def clean(self):
    ...
    if self.instance.pk is not None: # if edit then filter with id
        if not Student.objects.filter(room=new_room, id=self.instance.pk):
            ...
```

At the time of creation there is no id yet. You got id when you update existing record.

Comment: For some reason, the cleaned_data does not have this key,,,

Comment: What can this be related to?

Comment: I Added an id in class META . The "CheckInForm' object has no attribute 'id" error is no longer present , but the function does not work as before. The cleaned_data still doesn't have the "id" key

Comment: I guess you need to add check if it is create or update before filtering `Student` with `id`, watch update

Comment: The most interesting thing is that I can actually view the student id. a = Student.objects.get(room=523) and a.id.                                                                    But this key is not in the dictionary for some reason

Comment: And what about `self.instance.pk`? Try filter with it when edit.

Comment: To be honest, I didn 't understand how I should do it(

Comment: Oh! I apologize for the inattention!That solved my problem!Thank you very much ! You saved me a lot of time!